# Can I use wifi to broadcast a message containing plaintext, so any device nearby can receive it, even they are not mutually connected/authenticated?

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, broadcast

**Can I use wifi or Bluetooth to broadcast a message containing plaintext** (like “How are you?”), so any device nearby can receive it, **even they are not mutually connected (authenticated)?**

--I know normally devices need to be connected/paired before they can exchange or share information.
Here I am curious if there's a way to broadcast through wifi or Bluetooth hardware, in the old way like a radio station. So one device sends out information, and any nearby device can read it.

Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Yes, but it will not achieve much. For example, you can set your SSID to "How are you?". People trying to connect to a wifi network may see yours in the list of networks if they are close. Max length is 32 chars tho.

Comment: You can configure AirDrop so that anyone can AirDrop you anything without prior authentication IIRC. Quite a few people do.

Comment: @Gantendo: thank you. Sorry I didn't make this clear: what I meant is like peer-to-peer: e.g. from one cellphone to another that both have wifi hardware, or even between two computers, but not through a router.

Comment: You can set the SSID of the wifi hotspot on your cellphone. If you are near me, my phone can see the SSIDs of the available wifi networks, including yours. I can configure my laptop to be a mobile hotspot, and if yours is near mine then you'll see my SSID in the list of available wifi networks. No external router required.

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/hotspot-control-use-your-android-as-a-wireless-router/

Comment: @Gantendo. I see. That's a very smart way! Do you know how often a cellphone broadcasts its SSID? Once a second? And how fast does the receive side detect? I would like to have a rather efficient communication.

Comment: This site claims the SSID is broadcast every tenth of a second https://www.netspotapp.com/wifi-scanner/hidden-networks.html According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382566/how-often-does-android-system-scan-wifi the scan interval on the receiving side differs with the make and model of the receiving device.

Comment: This isn't an efficient way of communicating between two devices. The conventional methods are far far more efficient. I couldn't find a file size limit for AirDrop, but it is of course limited by a slow bluetooth connection which has a small range (compared to other methods of communication). Wifi broadcasting is limited by the antenna, and the speed will drastically reduce the further you are away.

Comment: Using the SSID to communicate anything other than the name of your network is highly inefficient due to the overhead https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_overhead and the 32char limit (which in reality would be even shorter because you'd need some kinda checksum https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum). Bluetooth is not intended for long distances and is slow. Sounds like an XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378 What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: This sounds rather like [BlueJacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluejacking), sending unsolicited messages to nearby devices.

Comment: @antendo: I was thinking these situations:  if a group of hikers get separated in a place with no cellular signal, and they want to get together somewhere. Or a guy gets lost somewhere, and he might use his cellphone send out SOS message with his gps location through wifi to anyone nearby. Maybe there are apps out there already? I really would like to see how to achieve this.

Comment: @Tetsujin. Thank you. That sounds another option. Comparing to wifi, Bluetooth might have much shorter range.

Comment: Re: your hiker scenario - you can shout further than wifi or Bluetooth.